# How does the ITRS frame related to ECEF frame?

Tags: frame-of-reference

How does the [International Terrestrial Reference frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Terrestrial_Reference_System) related to the [Earth-centered, Earth-fixed frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF), as both of them rotate with the Earth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple explanation:
The International Terrestrial Reference (ITR) Frame *is* an Earth-centered, Earth-fixed (ECEF) frame, but with the axes of the ITR frame precisely specified taking into consideration the movements of the Earth's crust due to plate tectonics.

[This website](https://confluence.qps.nl/qinsy/en/international-terrestrial-reference-frame-2014-itrf2014-29856813.html) may be useful.

Comment: İ know that it considers the tectonic movements, but does it make the ITR different from ECEF? If no, then ECEF also considers tectonic movements?

Comment: @TarlanMammadzada - There is no such thing as **the** ECEF. The ITRF is **an** ECEF.